# File copy into folder in window application

Tags: c#, winforms, file-upload, file-copying

I have read a csv file from a filedialog in window application.

No i wish to copy a particular file to a folder, which is generating a problem.

the code is as follows

```
OpenFileDialog op1 = new OpenFileDialog();
op1.Multiselect = false;
op1.ShowDialog();
op1.Filter = "allfiles|*.csv";
txtSearchName.Text = op1.FileName;


File.Copy(op1.FileName, "C:\\Users\\skysoft\\Documents\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\MailSend\\MailSend\\CsvFile\\" + op1.FileName);
```

what i am doing wrong in it please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would recommend always use the @ sign before path strings to avoid problems like yours:
you need 1 more back slash before "visual studio 2010". for example:

```
@"C:\Users\skysoft\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MailSend\MailSend\CsvFile\"
```

also, you are giving the method

```
"C:\\Users\\skysoft\\Documents\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\MailSend\\MailSend\\CsvFile\\" + op1.FileName
```

which translate to

```
"C:\\Users\\skysoft\\Documents\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\MailSend\\MailSend\\CsvFile\\" + "c:\\...."
```

you should do `Path.GetFileName(op1.FileName)` as keyboardP said or `op1.FileName.Substring(op1.LastIndexOf('\\'))`

Comment: Thanks Ma'am .. but now it says the given path format is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Check the string, theres a missing backslash \ before visual studio

```
File.Copy(op1.FileName, "C:\\Users\\skysoft\\Documents\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\MailSend\\MailSend\\CsvFile\\" + op1.FileName);
```

Comment: thanks sir.. now its say the following path format is not supported.. how to rectify it

Comment: what is the value of op1.FileName ? Make sure that you are not appending the file name and path to your output, since you're already specifying the path.

Answer (score 1):

`op1.FileName` contains the full path whereas you just want the filename when appending it to your destination directory.

```
using(OpenFileDialog op1 = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    op1.Multiselect = false;        
    op1.Filter = "allfiles|*.csv";
    op1.ShowDialog();
    txtSearchName.Text = op1.FileName;

    string dest = Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\skysoft\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MailSend\MailSend\CsvFile\", Path.GetFileName(op1.FileName));
    File.Copy(op1.FileName, dest);
}
```